# Error while generating a PDF file with Excel in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, pdf, interop

I have to generate an excel file and a PDF file from an asp.net application. I'm using the Interop assemblies and I can generate the excel file without any problem. But when I'm generating an pdf file with the add-in SaveAsPDFandXPS.exe I'm getting the next error:

> Exception HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

with a debug I see the error is in the next method which is used to export de PDF file:

```
_objWB.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, _nombreArchivo,
   Excel.XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard, false, false, Type.Missing,
   Type.Missing, false, Type.Missing);
```

Answer (score 1):

That might happen when the office version that you developed against is different from the one used at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot safely use Office Automation in a server process. The Automation APIs are developed for use in a desktop application only. They usually don't work in ASP.NET, or don't work reliably. There are also licensing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Office automation is in general horribly unreliable. Even Microsoft recommend against using it. You might be better off using a pdf generation library like Itextsharp or Crystal Reports.